# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of bigint or int

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading schema of the data frame from a text file. The file looks like

```
id,1,bigint
price,2,bigint
sqft,3,bigint
zip_id,4,int
name,5,string
```

and I am mapping parsed data types to Spark Sql datatypes.The code for creating data frame is -

```
var schemaSt = new ListBuffer[(String,String)]()
// read schema from file
for (line <- Source.fromFile("meta.txt").getLines()) {
  val word = line.split(",")
  schemaSt += ((word(0),word(2)))
}

// map datatypes
val types = Map("int" -> IntegerType, "bigint" -> LongType)
      .withDefault(_ => StringType)
val schemaChanged = schemaSt.map(x => (x._1,types(x._2))

// read data source
val lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("data source path")

val fields = schemaChanged.map(x => StructField(x._1, x._2, nullable = true)).toList

val schema = StructType(fields)

val rowRDD = lines
  .map(_.split("\t"))
  .map(attributes => Row.fromSeq(attributes))

// Apply the schema to the RDD
val new_df = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
new_df.show(5)
new_df.printSchema()
```

but the above works only for StringType. For IntegerType and LongType, it is throwing exceptions -

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of int

and

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of bigint.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and its cause is the `Row.fromSeq()` call.

If it is called on the array of `String`, the resulting `Row` is the row of `String`'s. Which does not match the type of the 2nd column in your schema (`bigint` or `int`).

In order to get the valid dataframe as a result of `Row.fromSeq(values: Seq[Any])`, the elements of the `values` argument have to be of the type that corresponds to your schema.

Answer (score 10):

You are trying to store strings in numerically typed columns.

You need to cast string encoded numerical data to the appropriate numerical types while parsing.